# Custom format string : arguments in double brackets java

Tags: java, android, formatting

I am working on android project but I retrieve from a server a `.xml` file with all localisations strings. I face a problem because when the string can include an argument, this argument is set in double brackets like :

> You have {{0}} dollar(s) on your account

I can't use the regular `String.format()` function. I don't really see how could I resolve this, should I create a custom formatter?

EDIT: The string can have more than one parameter

Thx

Comment: Uh, resolve what?

Comment: How can I do something like `String.format("You have {{0}} dollar(s) on your account", 120)` and this will return **You have 120 dollar(s) on you account**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant way would be to use a Regex: `{{((.*?)*?)}}`, which I was using in `c#`.

https://regexr.com/3tkl9

This will allow you to extract the values as well.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("{{((.*?)*?)}}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    // Other stuff, like extracting values
    String value = matcher.group(1)
    // Then you can just String.replace the matches.
}
```

To create a function with more parameters:

```
public String format(String input, String... args) {
    // To access an element use e.g. args[0];
}
```

A full working function might be something like this (didn't test):

```
public String format(String input, String... args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("{{((.*?)*?)}}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String value = matcher.group(1);
        // TODO: error handling
        int index = Integer.parseInt(value);
        if (index < args.length) {
            input.replace(matcher.group(), args[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Giovanni `int index = Integer.parseInt(value);` may be throw exception ?

Comment: Yes, you need to check what the value is, and if it's a digit or not.

Comment: It will crash if the match is something like `{{iAmNotADigit}}`

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.replace()` instead of String.format().

You can also replace multiple parameters Like,

```
String s = "{{0}} is friend with {{1}}"; 
s = s.replace("{{0}}","ABC"); 
s = s.replace("{{1}}","PQR");
```

Comment: Okay thanks, is there any way to make a custom formatter which can take more than one parameter?

Comment: All the parameter name are different ?

Comment: Yes for example "{{0}} is friend with {{1}}"

Comment: Is there any way to create function like `myFormatter("{{0}} is friend with {{1}}","William", "Antoine")` and this function could also work with one or more parameters

Comment: How you can pass multiple parameter to that function?

Comment: `public void myFormatter(String template, String... args){
    // method body
}` This way

Comment: @AntoineD I wrote some example function for you.